# Discord.py can't define channel

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that sends a welcome message to a specified channel in the .jason file. So it could be compatible with multiple servers. But it runs into an error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def welcomeMessage(ctx):
    with open("guild.json", "r") as f:
        guildInfo = json.load(f)

    guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id] = ctx.message.channel.id #sets the channel it was sent to as the default welcome message channel

    with open("guild.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(guildInfo, f)


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open("guild.json", "r") as f:
        guildInfo = json.load(f)

    channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id] #this keeps causing the error
    
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x07faf6, description=f"***Welcome to the Server***")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I have got everything working except this:

```
channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id]
```

It keeps giving me this error:

```
    channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id]
AttributeError: module 'ctx' has no attribute 'message'
```

Comment: you are trying to access `ctx` without passing it as a parameter for `on_member_ready`. that means, you will need to set the channel id somewhere you can access from both `welcomeMessage` and `on_member_ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_member_join` event does not provide a context. Luckily, the member passed to the `on_member_join` event has a [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild) attribute capturing the guild the member belongs to (or in this case, joined). Replace your `ctx.message.guild.id` by `member.guild.id` and you should be good

Comment: Now it's working but it's taking the id of the server, not the channels id:   channnel = guildInfo[member.guild.id]
KeyError: 735082582705700904

Comment: You need to make sure the channel is defined for each server the bot is in, or else you will get a `KeyError`

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: wrap the `channel=guildInfo[member.guild.id]`-line in a `try ... except`-block and exit on `KeyError` (that means that the server this member joined has not defined a welcome channel and most likely doesn't want to use the feature)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Lukas Thaler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66569303/5446749), I redid the code and it works:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def welcomechannel(ctx):
    fileopen = str(ctx.message.guild.id) + ".json"
    file = open(fileopen, "w")
    data = {}
    data["channel"] = ctx.message.channel.id
    json.dump(data, file)
    print("The channel has been added to the list")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    colours = [0x3348FF, 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF]
    try:
        fileopen = str(member.guild.id) + ".json"
        file = open(fileopen, "r")
        data = json.load(file)

        channelid = data["channel"]
        channel = client.get_channel(id=channelid)

    
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=random.choice(colours), description="***Welcome***")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
        embed.set_author(name=f"{member.name}", icon_url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{member.guild}", icon_url=f"{member.guild.icon_url}")
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

    except:
        print("The server doesn't have a welcome channel")
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66568478/3) to the question [Discord.py can't define channel [fixed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568478/discord-py-cant-define-channel-fixed) by the OP [McBigBob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14846020/mcbigbob) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>